# JavaScript: compare two arrays of objects and highlight the differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My server streams array of objects every 5 seconds. Every array looks like that:

```
[
{"ticker":"AAPL", "price":"122.99","change":"92.48","change_percent":"0.43","dividend":"0.76","yield":"1.09"}
{"ticker":"GOOGL", "price":"190.84","change":"66.81","change_percent":"0.16","dividend":"0.42","yield":"1.48"}
{"ticker":"MSFT", "price":"235.81","change":"24.21","change_percent":"0.77","dividend":"0.12","yield":"1.97"}
{"ticker":"AMZN", "price":"291.58","change":"132.05","change_percent":"0.61","dividend":"0.83","yield":"0.42"}
{"ticker":"FB", "price":"242.28","change":"124.25","change_percent":"0.15","dividend":"0.63","yield":"0.97"}
{"ticker":"TSLA", "price":"299.61","change":"9.71","change_percent":"0.27","dividend":"0.53","yield":"1.51"}
]
```

Every five seconds my React app outputs this data to the browser.

My goal is to compare the old and new prices. If the price has decreased, color it green, and if it has increased, color it red.

Now I'm in trouble. What could be the logic behind the solution?

Comment: What did you tried so far ? SO is to help developers facing issues in implementation or logics not for creating the solutions.

Comment: Also more info on the arrays data would be good. For example the `change` or `change_percent`, is it always a positive integer or negative as well?

Comment: So far I've read a ton of tips on this site and haven't found any useful information :(

I have redux reducer in my App, so I can access the previous array, as well as new array. I think about to take the prices from both of them and then compare. If the difference is negative, I will write the value "false" to the variable, and "true" if the difference is positive. Then, I can create the HTML tag style which will change depending on the value of the variable.

Comment: @Hoargarth I'm  only interested to highlight the price, nothing more. UPDATE: But you're right! If it can take negative and positive values, then the task is simplified. I will check it. UPDATE2: Unfortunately, the values you talked about always positive, so I can't use it.

Comment: Then yes, it's like you mentioned. You have to take previous array and current array and calculate the difference between prices.